# PHP Errors after OS X Upgrade

Tags: control-panel, focus-lab-master-config

I got to work this morning and, after upgrading to Yosemite and MAMP Pro, I am getting a series of PHP Errors and cannot get access to to CP (returns blank page).
The frontend of the site itself is fetching data from the DB but the issue appears to be with the config file? I'm using FocusLabs Master Config too.

The first error is

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 242`

The warnings after that are "Cannot modify header information" warnings.

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/bjh/github/beacon/lighthouse/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/EE_Input.php
Line Number: 212`

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/bjh/github/beacon/lighthouse/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/EE_Input.php
Line Number: 212`

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/bjh/github/beacon/lighthouse/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/EE_Input.php
Line Number: 212`

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/bjh/github/beacon/lighthouse/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/EE_Input.php
Line Number: 212`

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/bjh/github/beacon/lighthouse/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 446`

After pulling the working copy of our site from the dev server and copying the DB it appears as though this issue is only occurring locally. :-/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OSX Yosemite, MAMP, Apache, and PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm getting the same issue since upgrading to OS X Yosemite.

I suspect the real issue is your version of PHP has been upgraded to PHP 5.6.

While upgrading the OS I also swapped to PHP 5.6 and now all EE sites with debug mode enabled display this PHP notice.

Someone else on the EllisLab forums has had the same issue and a fix has been posted:
https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/244510/#1066393

## UPDATE

Sorry guys, I should have provided a code sample to the fix originally in the event that the linked page disappears.

Replace the last line in the `&get_config()` method of `system/codeigniter/system/core/Common.php` like so:

`-      return $_config[0] =& $config;
+       $_config[0] =& $config;
+
+       return $_config[0];`

This should fix the issue.

Comment: The link to the solution on ellislabs.com is now dead. Could you update your answer with the fix if possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your system is using the bundled version of Apache/PHP rather than MAMP's version. You need to stop (and disable) the system version and ensure the MAMP version is started.

Answer (score 0):

Update your php file system "system/core/Common.php" in mac mini(OS X Yosemite) like so:

Bellow code in "Common.php" :

```
      return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

Replace by bellow code :

```
   $_config[0] =& $config;
   return $_config[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to set permissions on the local cache folder to 777.

Comment: Try too to empty your cache if it's related to the chmod setting